# How to play .swf with flash player lite in android 2.2 sdk in java?

Tags: java, android

How can I get the full path of flash player lite,

and use it to play my target `.swf` ?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't know if you can call flash player from outside a browser. What you can do is, create an activity containing a WebView, embed the .swf into a HTML webpage, load that page in the webview, and you should have a working flash thingy. HTML is easy to style using CSS and javascript, in case you want buttons on the same page etc. You won't however be able to achieve a true native look and view. With HTML5 you can get quite close though.

Should you really want that "native" looking application, you can extract the images that android OS uses and style your page to android style. If the version number changes(for example, android uses new native look and feel), your page wont automagically adjust it's style though.

Refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543349/load-local-html-in-webview) on how to load local html files into a webview.