# Load HTML file into WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, local

I have a local html page along with several other resources pointed by it (css files and Javascript libraries) that I would like to load into a WebView . How could this be achieved ?

Perhaps not the best way to procede but I'm still experimenting.

Comment: for me it worked if I dropped the dot html -webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename");

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to accept @Joe's answer?

Answer (score 373):

The easiest way would probably be to put your web resources into the **assets folder** then call:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");
```

For Complete Communication between Java and Webview [See This](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-webview-loading-custom-html-and.html)

Update: The assets folder is usually the following folder: 
`<project>/src/main/assets`
This can be changed in the asset folder configuration setting in your **`<app>.iml` file** as:

`<option name=”ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH” value=”/src/main/assets” />`
See Article [Where to place the assets folder in Android Studio](https://web.archive.org/web/20181111063256/http://envyandroid.com/assets-android-studio/)

Comment: This problem is really an FAQ.

Comment: What other ways would there be ?

Comment: You could presumably also load it form a String if you're very adverse to using assets...(see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543349/load-local-html-in-webview)

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer, `cause it really is.

Comment: If the assets path ever changes this will break.

Comment: @SK9 The same applies if any other asset or expected file is missing, like if you change the name of your starting activity class and don't update `AndroidManifest.xml` to reflect that. (Personally, I'd recommend putting the URL/file path in string resources and accessing it from there such that the path is with all the other string data for the program, but that isn't really directly related to the issue of asset/resource dependency.)

Comment: for me it worked if I dropped the dot html -webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename");

Comment: For those don't know how to create assets folder, right click on "app"->"New"->"Folder"->"Assets Folder", and click "Finish". Android Studio will create the assets folder in correct path. And you just need to move your html file to the new assets folder. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio

Comment: Yes, this is working, but it shows incorrectly non english letters.

Comment: I have same problem for ios, does anyone have come across this problem? If yes please share your solution i tried different way to access but it of no use , i tried solution https://forum.qt.io/topic/47495/upload-ios-image-with-qt/11

Comment: Android Studio doesn't seem to have the "New > Assets Folder" option anymore. Updated the answer to include the proper file path. Note that `assets` is parallel to `res` folder-structure wise.

Answer (score 30):

probably this sample could help:

```
  WebView lWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
  File lFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "<FOLDER_PATH_TO_FILE>/<FILE_NAME>");
  lWebView.loadUrl("file:///" + lFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: in the example there that have the html in external memory, it is best to have it packaged within the application

Comment: "file:///" is important when using HTML file from local device directory. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In this case, using `WebView#loadDataWithBaseUrl()` is better than `WebView#loadUrl()`!

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, 
        data,
        "text/html",
        "utf-8",
        null);
```

url: url/path String pointing to the directory all your JavaScript files and html links have their origin. If null, it's about:blank.
data: String containing your hmtl file, read with BufferedReader for example

More info: [WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: What is **data** variable?  Please provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

The Accepted Answer is not working for me, This is what works for me

```
WebSettings webSetting = webView.getSettings();
    webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

   webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Comment: Whats is the version of your Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

XML Layout File:

```
<WebView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activities.Bani9">
</WebView>
```

Java Code:

```
public class Bani9 extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bani9);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSetting = webView.getSettings();
        webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/punjabi/bani9.html");
    }
}
```

Make sure you set file path accurately.
[image: Make sure you set File Path properly]

Answer (score 1):

From the official guide https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/load-local-content :

1. Store the HTML as an asset in `app/src/main/assets/`
2. Use [`WebViewAssetLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader) to load the asset. Construct it in your `onCreate()` as follows:

```
final WebViewAssetLoader assetLoader = new WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
         .addPathHandler("/assets/", new WebViewAssetLoader.AssetsPathHandler(this))
         .addPathHandler("/res/", new WebViewAssetLoader.ResourcesPathHandler(this))
         .build();
```

3. Subclass [`WebViewClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) to wrap `WebViewAssetLoader`:

```
private static class LocalContentWebViewClient extends WebViewClientCompat {

    private final WebViewAssetLoader mAssetLoader;

    LocalContentWebViewClient(WebViewAssetLoader assetLoader) {
        mAssetLoader = assetLoader;
    }

    @Override
    @RequiresApi(21)
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                     WebResourceRequest request) {
        return mAssetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.getUrl());
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // to support API < 21
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                     String url) {
        return mAssetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(Uri.parse(url));
    }
}
```

This basically passes the request URL to `WebViewAssetLoader` to load web content from an asset.

4. Use `assetLoader` from (2) to construct `WebViewClient` from (3), and set it in your `WebView`. Your `index.html` can be loaded by using https and the default domain `appassets.androidplatform.net`:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new LocalContentWebViewClient(assetLoader));
mWebView.loadUrl("https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/index.html");
```

Note that loading local files using web-like URLs instead of `file://` is desirable as it is compatible with the Same-Origin policy.