# How do I get my android webview make a load locally

Tags: android, webview, cocoonjs, construct-2

I have a doubt. What happens is the following: 
I exported my game by using cocoonjs contruct 2, but I want to run it on my android webview by, because I want to implement starApp, and cocoonjs not support this. 
So, using my code below, I get only a blank screen. 
But in my launcher cocoonjs, this same project works normally, just that I select Canvas + can anyone help me?

```
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webInicial); 
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.loadData(yourData, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Where youData is the actual HTML data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("www/index.html");`?

If that doesn't work, I'd say try the solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749569/load-local-html-file-into-webview) and let us know if it worked for you.