# I cannot show a local html file on a webview in Android

Tags: android, webview

I have a listview from which I pick the html file and I want the file to be displayed in webview which takes the 1/4 of a 10' tablet I try the following but nothing happens and I get a white webview

```
ListFiles.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            String filename = ListFiles.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            myweb.setInitialScale(1);
            myweb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myweb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            myweb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            myweb.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            myweb.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
            myweb.reload();
            myweb.loadUrl(dirFiles + "/" + filename);

        }
    });
```

Comment: what is `dirFiles`? Make sure it is a URL, for example `file:/// ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749569/load-local-html-file-into-webview

Answer (score 1):

I converted to Uri with

```
String WebFile = dirFiles+"/"+filename;
Uri WebfileUri  = Uri.fromFile(new File(WebFile));
myweb.loadUrl(WebfileUri.toString());
```

and worked

Answer (score 0):

**try to below :-**

```
File lFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "<FOLDER_PATH_TO_FILE>/<FILE_NAME>");
WebView.loadUrl("file:///" + lFile.getAbsolutePath());
```