# Android Studio Webview 1101 Activity

Tags: java, android, webview, error-handling

I am very close to releasing my app but i am stuck, the app is a webview with push notifications which works as i require, but i need webview to show a basic activity page when a 1101 (offline) message occurs.

This is the activity as it currently stands.

```
package kixx.uk.co.selectparkhomesamazonpush;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.app.Application;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;
ProgressBar progressBar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.selectparkhomes.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());


}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)
    {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{ //if back key is pressed
    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)&& mWebView.canGoBack())
    {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;

    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

All help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load a html file from asset into the web view. Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749569/load-local-html-file-into-webview)