# WebView not loading local HTML in Android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to load a local html file in a WebView but it always give error
new::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
I have attached the images of code I am using and the file directory. I have tried it with different directories but it didn't work.

Changed the file directory to res folder, res/raw folder.
tried to load different html
it does load the webvlinks

Path and the code image is here

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load HTML file into WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749569/load-html-file-into-webview)

Comment: thats the only webview on the page and only htmlfile  in sampledata

Comment: Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5749641/10941112

Answer (score 5):

It is good to place all file assets files in the assets folder.
So Add your HTML file to the assets folder and load webview with below code.

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/privacy_policy.html");
```

Or if you don't want to move the file from that "sampledata" folder, then use below code.

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///sampledata/privacy_policy.html");
```

Comment: asset folder and raw folder is that different?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I found this answer here: https://inneka.com/programming/android/loading-html-file-to-webview-on-android-from-assets-folder-using-android-studio-2/

```
try {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
    InputStream stream = assetManager.open("editor.html");
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        total.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, total.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
} catch (Exception xxx) {
```