# Android WebView deny internet access?

Tags: android, security, webview, android-webview

I want to run untrusted code (from npm) in a webview, loaded from within the app as described in [Load HTML file into WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749569/load-html-file-into-webview) . This is because there's js libs that do what I want for a specific activity and reimplenting them in Android native code will be a huge project.

I don't want the code I fetch from npm to be able to leak information to some random server on the internet. Can I disable internet access on a WebView?

I'll do my own app IO via foreign interface calls on the Android object, where I can lock down the attack surface significantly.