# How can i use my css file in my html file on android?

Tags: android, html, css, web, mobile-website

I created a html website with css on my computer and it works pefect on it. But i wanted it to work on android too, so i created a folder and just moved the files in it. As i opened the html file, the css file didn't work.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Home">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Home">
    <meta name="author" content="Censored">
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
```

[An image from the html & css files folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyyh6.png)

Comment: If you hava a website then why can't you use android webview?

Comment: Browsers on android have security concerns with local HTML files; I was frustrated by this recently myself - basically you need a webserver to host the file. Means you need network available.

Comment: It depends on how you open the html file. You did not tell us what you did.

Answer (score 0):

The webview approach should work, but it means you'll have to write up an app for every scenario.

[Load HTML file into WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749569/load-html-file-into-webview)