# How to display the HttpResponse page in an android activity

Tags: android, http-post, httpresponse

I made an HttpPost to "https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp"

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String URL = (String) "https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp";
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
```

When executed in a the background

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
Log.d("Response", response.toString());
```

logCat displays this "org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@413f0a28"

how do i display the resulting page, which should be this "https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/std_Alert.asp" when accessed from a pc.

Answer (score 2):

`response.toString()` will print the object reference not the content. What you want is to read the response content and covert it to `String`. The simplest way to do this is using `EntityUtils.toString()` class, here is an example:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
String responseContent = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
Log.d("Response", responseContent );
```

Comment: thanks that helped me see the code of the responding page in logCat, but how do i display the responding page in a new activity? that is my original question.

i have the login creds. in the opening/main activity, after login button is pressed, the code is executed in the background, and a response is received in the main_activity.java. how do i take the responding page and display it in a new activity.

if you wish to see the repsonding page i can lend you a id and password.

Comment: and if i have to use a webview how would i get the response and set the webview, i am not planning to use a webview if it looks just like how it would do on a browser, then users can just use the browser on the phone, however i am willing to do this initially, to get started.

again if you wish to see the response page i can provide a login cred, please ask
note:im new to android development

Comment: `WebView` will make the page look like the browser. See this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543349/load-local-html-in-webview 

If you want to display `native` anrdoid interface, your website should be exposing sort of `APIs` that you can use to receive the information

Answer (score 0):

I do this in the following class.  You can use this library in your project or you can just copy the code.

https://github.com/aguynamedrich/beacon-utils/blob/master/Library/src/us/beacondigital/utils/StringUtils.java

Here are the important methods:

```
public static String readStream(HttpResponse response) {
    String data = null;
    try
    {
        data = readStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { }
    return data;
}


public static String readStream(InputStream in)
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try
    {
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { }
    finally
    {
        IOUtils.safeClose(in);
        IOUtils.safeClose(reader);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and from another class (used above):

https://github.com/aguynamedrich/beacon-utils/blob/master/Library/src/us/beacondigital/utils/IOUtils.java

```
public static void safeClose(Closeable closeable)
{
    if(closeable != null)
    {
        try
        {
            closeable.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To toString wont work there you need to read from response stream:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = response.getEntity().getContent().read(buffer, 0, 1024);
String responseContent = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

You may need to increase buffer size or to read data in blocks but this is what you need.

Comment: This will code trim the `response` if it is more than `1024`?