# How can i load a link in other net browser that i am showing in my web view?

Tags: android

I load data from html to web view and there are link some where of my data that load in  web view and i want when i click them there should be function call as complete action using.
So i can load that link in other net browser.

Comment: paste some code you have tried yet. As far as I understand your question you should use 
`WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
  
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.loadUrl(url);`

Comment: i am using this  web1.loadData(htmldata,"text/html; charset=utf-8",null);    as i have to load html data in web view and that is happening but the data i load like - read more go to google.com.... so i need when i click on google.com that is shown in my web view that open in my other web browser

Comment: so, you are not using any `url` to load into the `webview` ?

Comment: no how can i load a string in webView.loadUrl(url); so i am using  web1.loadData(htmldata,"text/html; charset=utf-8",null);

Comment: you have your html file copy that file into your project's `Assets` folder and then load that file using `web1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourHtmlFileName.html");`

Comment: It like this String htmldata = "<html>d</html>" here d is the string that content the value of pares data by json. now how can copy that to my assets folder. please help

Comment: you should take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4543485/3982085

Comment: can you please help in how to copy the <html></html> to assets folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Ref. from: [Link should be open in same web view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7309017/1318946)

Keep Googling :)

Comment: sorry its not helping me

Comment: i want to open link in other browser not in same web view

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample html for example:

```
<html>
<body>
    This is some string
</body>
</html>
```

Save this html file as "filename.html" on your desktop

Now copy that file and paste into your `Assets` folder

After that go to your Java code and write code:

```
web1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");
```

**EDITED**

Here is another way if you want dynamic value as content of your html see below

```
String d = "your dynamic string value";

String your_html = "<html><body>"+d+"</body></html>";

web1.loadData(your_html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: thnxs it done. can you tell me if i want to do like this how can i  String d = "This is some string" then in assets folder <html><body>+d+</body></html> then in activity web1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");

Comment: yha i am doing this but id and case if my string d = "read more go to www.google.com" and when i do web1.loadData(your_html, "text/html", "UTF-8"); its done but when i click on www.google.com i need it open in other net browser not in my application

Comment: I edited again my answer see now use `web1.loadData(your_html, "text/html", "UTF-8");`

Comment: @HiteshMatnani now check my edit its working on my side.

Comment: `web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);  web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` add these two statements before `web1.loadData`

Comment: yha checked thanks for it @XtreemDeveloper but i need is that - d = "read more go to www.google.com" and when i do web1.loadData(your_html, "text/html", "UTF-8"); its done but when i click on www.google.com i need it open in other net browser not in my application